# Presented Modal view controller not displayed like a Form

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog, modalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am new to iOS programming. I am learning How to use Modal in iOS. I have a button. Inside button tap handler. I want to show a UIViewController like Modal form.

**Here is my code:**

```
@IBAction func userEditClick(sender: AnyObject) {

    let userCtrl = UserEditViewController(nibName: "UserEditViewController", bundle: nil)
    userCtrl.callback = self

    userCtrl.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet
    //userCtrl.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 800);

    self.presentViewController(userCtrl, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

UserEditViewController is showed BUT the screen look like Normal UIViewController -> This is not what I expected ---> Form Modal

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK form sheets are only for iPads, if you want to replicate that on iPhones you need to probably build a custom view yourself, or find an open source component that does it already.

Answer (score 1):

You just call presentViewController. That will do the job. The default animation of the presentViewController is modal. Also when you see the documentation it says that the setting will adapt to the environment. So I think when you are on the iPhone the FormSheet have to cover the whole screen. I think you may stick to the apple's default behavior.

> In a horizontally regular environment, a presentation style that
>   displays the content centered in the screen. The width and height of
>   the content area are smaller than the screen size and a dimming view
>   is placed underneath the content. If the device is in a landscape
>   orientation and the keyboard is visible, the position of the view is
>   adjusted upward so that the view remains visible. All uncovered areas
>   are dimmed to prevent the user from interacting with them.
>
> In a horizontally compact environment, this option behaves the same as
>   UIModalPresentationFullScreen.
>
> Available in iOS 3.2 and later.

Ok so if you want to show like form sheet on the iPhone or iPad you need to calculate the size and show them with the animation you make and load it on your view controller.

Or you can check this repository https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController
They did the hard parts :)

Comment: You want to do it on the iPhone?

Comment: Thank you. I get it now.